# Angular native component i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am trying to to find a way to translate strings in my components or services, but the only way I find leads me to the angular-translate plugin. Is there any straight forward way to do it without plugins?

Comment: [The built-in one ?](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Comment: any functionality in angular is some sort of component anyway, either buildin or third party, how about https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Yes, I know of the npx-translate plugin. I am asking for a "native" way.

@Exlord - How do I do it in the typescript file?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a dictionnary, a huge array KEY => WORD and use Angular Pipes : https://angular.io/guide/pipes

I used http://www.ngx-translate.com/ for translating an application in 12 languages with a huge hand-made translation tool for translators.
It works perfectly and it's really flexible !

I hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the ngx-translate plugin for my component files, but in the HTML I still use the i18n attribute. Not the finest solution, but it will do for now.